# Proof of Crapo's complementation theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattice-theory, mobius-inversion

In Crapo's work "[Möbius inversion in lattices](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01899388)," he gave a second proof of his complementation theorem:
$$ \mu(0,1) = \sum_{x, y \in s^\perp} \mu(0,x) \zeta(x, y) \mu(y,1)$$
where $s$ is an arbitrary element of the lattice $L$ and $s^\perp$ is the set of the complements of $s$.

The proof claims that a set $A$ disjoint from $s^\perp \cup \{0\}$ spans $L$ (i.e., $\inf A = 0$ and $\sup A = 1$) iff $A \cup \{0\}$ spans $L$. The only if part is clear but I cannot understand why the if part is true. For example, taking $A = 1$ would yield a counterexample?

This argument is also briefly mentioned in Martin Aigner's book Combinatorial Theory (page 180, exercise IV.3.13).

Any help would be appreciated! (I know there is another proof of this result, though.)

Comment: Without having read the paper, I am getting the impression that this proof is indeed wrong. Toggling $0$ preserves $\operatorname{sup} A = 1$ but doesn't preserve $\operatorname{inf} A = 0$. It wouldn't surprise me if the trick to fixing the proof is by proving a one-sided analogue of Corollary 1, in which the requirement $\operatorname{inf} A = 0$ is removed from the definition of "spanning".

Comment: Thank you for the comment! What is puzzling is that if this proof is indeed problematic, why no correction was made when this paper was included in "Classic Papers in Combinatorics" (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4842-8_29)... For this reason I tend to believe maybe I am missing something...

Comment: I don't think any corrections have been made in the volume you referenced. The editors seem to have taken the lazy route.